# How to delete a chart (canvas) out of its scope?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, chart.js

I need to figure out how to delete this chart because when I create a new one in the same spot, the previous one still shows through. The user originally selects something from a dropdown. Based on that the js does a `$http.get()` request to a url. Then it creates a chart with that data, and refreshes the chart every x seconds. When a user selects something different from the dropdown, it does the same process, but for some reason I can't seem to destroy the old chart. You can see I tried to attempt so @ `//$scope.myChart.destroy()` but at that point it says that my chart isn't defined.

It makes sense because when a new item is selected in the dropdown, it basically calls all of this over again from the beginning. Which means that it wouldn't know what `$scope.myChart` is. But then how would I destroy it?

If it is indefinitely in the `$interval` loop until something is selected, it wouldn't know it needs to be destroyed until something has changed. But at that point, is it too late to tell it to destroy?

Here is the js for everything:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myapp', ['cgOwf'])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, owf, $interval) {
    var infractions;
    var url = 'http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxx';
    var fullUrl = '';
    var mainInterval = '';
    $scope.username = '';
    $scope.totalscore = '';
    $scope.mychart = '';

    owf.ready(function() {
      fullUrl = null;
      owf.Eventing.subscribe('user-status', function(sender, msg, channel) {
        $scope.doughnutData = [];
        //myChart = '';
        console.debug('[%s] - received message %o inside of user card', channel, msg);
        $interval.cancel(mainInterval);
        fullUrl = url + msg;
        console.debug("Going to " + fullUrl + " inside of user card.");
        $http.get(fullUrl).success(function (returnedData) {
            console.debug("HOOOOORAY!?");

            $scope.username = returnedData.name;
            $scope.totalscore = returnedData.totalScore;

            console.debug("username " + $scope.username);
            console.debug("totalscore " + $scope.totalscore);

            returnedData.models.forEach(function (x) {
                console.debug("made it inside of forEach");
                console.debug(x.score);

                if (x.score >= 75) {
                    $scope.doughnutData.push({
                        'value': x.score,
                            'color': '#F7464A',
                            'highlight': '#FF5A5E',
                            'label': x.name
                    });
                    console.debug("pushed red");
                } else if (x.score >= 50) {
                    $scope.doughnutData.push({
                        'value': x.score,
                            'color': '#FDB45C',
                            'highlight': '#FFC870',
                            'label': x.name
                    });
                    console.debug("pushed yellow");
                } else {
                    $scope.doughnutData.push({
                        'value': x.score,
                            'color': '#424242',
                            'highlight': '#686868',
                            'label': x.name
                    });
                    console.debug("pushed grey");
                }

            });
            $scope.doughnutData = sortByKey($scope.doughnutData, 'value');
            //$scope.myChart.destroy();
            var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
            $scope.myChart = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut($scope.doughnutData, {
                responsive: true
            });
        });
        mainInterval = $interval(function () {
            $scope.doughnutData = [];
            $http.get(fullUrl).success(function (returnedData) {
                $scope.username = returnedData.name;
                $scope.totalscore = returnedData.totalScore.toFixed(3);

                returnedData.models.forEach(function (x) {
                    if (x.score >= 75) {
                        $scope.doughnutData.push({
                            'value': x.score,
                                'color': '#F7464A',
                                'highlight': '#FF5A5E',
                                'label': x.name
                        });
                    } else if (x.score >= 50) {
                        $scope.doughnutData.push({
                            'value': x.score,
                                'color': '#FDB45C',
                                'highlight': '#FFC870',
                                'label': x.name
                        });
                    } else {
                        $scope.doughnutData.push({
                            'value': x.score,
                                'color': '#424242',
                                'highlight': '#686868',
                                'label': x.name
                        });
                    }
                });
                $scope.doughnutData = sortByKey($scope.doughnutData, 'value');
                $scope.myChart.destroy();
                var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
                $scope.myChart = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut($scope.doughnutData, {
                    responsive: true
                });
            });
        }, 10000);
        $scope.$apply();
      });
    });

    function sortByKey(array, key) {
      return array.sort(function(a, b) {
        var x = a[key];
        var y = b[key];
        return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
      });
    }

    $scope.launchIAT = function() {
      console.debug("Launching the IAT tool now.");
      owf.Launcher.launch({
        universalName: 'com.gdms.IAT',
        launchOnlyIfClosed: true
      });
    };

    $scope.setColor = function(score) {
      if (score >= 75) {
        return {
          background: '#FF4747',
          color: '#FFFFFF'
        }
      } else if (score >= 50 && score < 75) {
        return {
          background: '#FFFF47'
        }
      }
    };

  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps make `.destroy` conditional in your dropdown handler instead. That way it won't blow up the first time through when there's no `myChart` defined:

```
if($scope.myChart){$scope.myChart.destroy()};
```

Comment: Holy crap man. I have been banging my head on the wall for hours. This instantly fixed my problem. Thanks.